# How do I get the image that is submitted with a post, when I'm in the loop?

Tags: posts, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm using Gravity Forms to create a form. The form entry is created as a post.
I have a loop that successfully gets the content of the post.

However, I'd also like to get the image that is submitted with the post.
I have this snippet:

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_link($POST->ID) ; ?>
```

However, this makes returns nothing.
This makes me think that either the code is incorrect, or that GF is storing the image in a way that differs from how normal post images are stored.

This is my full loop:

```
<?php global $query_string ; ?>
  <?php  $my_query = new WP_Query('&cat=4&posts_per_page=10') ?>
  <?php  while ( $my_query->have_posts())  : $my_query->the_post() ; ?>
  <ul>
    <li>
   <img src="<?php wp_get_attachment_link() ; ?> " class="" alt="#" />
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"  title="Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <?php the_content() ;?>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I get the image?

Comment: By default, `wp_get_attachment_link()` returns either a link to an image or `Missing Attachment` - have you tried to do `die( var_dump( wp_get_attachment_link( $post->ID ) ) );` to see what's returned?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to identify the attachments in a post:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts($args);
foreach($images as $image){
   echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'size')
}
```